# Extjs Combo box in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and is currently struggling with extjs combo box. I saw your post on stackoverflow. Can you please help me with the solution?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: To whom you are referring exactly? Can you be more particular with some code snippets and logs with issue you are facing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.